# How to filter DataGridView using multiple ComboBoxes?

Tags: c#, filter, datagridview, combobox

I am very new to coding and am trying to learn C# through little project.
I spent a week or more trying to find solution but although there is many threads, none of them made sense for me and couldn't get it to work.

I have a Form with a DataGridView and I want to create 6 ComboBoxes to filter it. All with same data source.
I managed so far to get DataGridView working with one ComboBox but don't know how to add more of them.

My code:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class frmEmpList : Form
{
    private void frmEmpList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PopulateCombobox();
        this.PopulateDataGridView();
    }

    private void PopulateCombobox()
    {
        string qry = "SELECT DISTINCT LastName FROM Employees";
        string constr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-Q2B3UUH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PeopleManager;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = "";
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

            cbLastName.DataSource = dt;
            cbLastName.DisplayMember = "LastName";
            cbLastName.ValueMember = "LastName";
        }
    }

    private void PopulateDataGridView()
    {
        string query = "SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, Role, Grade, Dept, Shift FROM Employees";
        query += " WHERE LastName = @LastName";
        query += " OR ISNULL(@LastName, '') = ''";
        string constr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-Q2B3UUH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PeopleManager;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", cbLastName.SelectedValue);
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                dgEmpList.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
    }

    private void cbLastName_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PopulateDataGridView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change `("@LastName", cbLastName.SelectedValue)` to `("@LastName", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cbLastName.SelectedValue as string) ? DBNull.Value : ((string)cbLastName.SelectedValue).Trim())`

Then

```
query += " WHERE LastName = @LastName";
query += " OR ISNULL(@LastName, '') = ''";
```

To

```
query += " WHERE (@LastName IS NULL OR LastName = @LastName)";
```

If you need more filters for your query just add more filters like this

```
query += " AND (@FooBar IS NULL OR FooBar = @FooBar)";
```

You can also create dynamic script by only including filters you need in your script. First filter needs to use `WHERE` and others `AND`

Comment: What is the benefit of changing how above query is formulated? The only difference I can see is that with original there is preview of all records in datagridview until user select criteria and with yours there is no records visible until any criteria is selected. Personally I'd prefer first option :)

Comment: Unfortunately with first change you suggested as soon as I paste it, "IsNullOrWhitespace" is underlined and it states "string does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhitespace'", however as soon I apply suggested fix and run the app I get error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@LastName nvarchar(4000))SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, Rol' expects the parameter '@LastName', which was not supplied.'"....

Comment: @DanielIttrich Fixed null should have been DBNull.Value. I've been using Dapper instead of SqlCommand so long that I forgot.